# Bootstrap 4 - Navbar doesn't work

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am following *Gary Simon's* tutorial [here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/74/Bootstrap-4-Navbar-Navigation-Tutorial) and when I copy and paste his navbar onto my body tag, I don't have the content on the right.

[image: navbar problem]

Gary Simon's tutorial is using `v4.0.0-alpha.6` while I am using `v4.0.0-beta.2`. Is this the problem?

Here is my code (copied from his tutorial):

```
<body>
    <div id="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse">

                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand text-primary" id="logo">GAMELOGO</a>

                    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="#">Overview</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="#">Specs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="#">FAQ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-primary" href="#">Purchase</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried getting the same effect by following the Bootstrap 4 docs [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#base-nav), but I can't get the same view as his tutorial.

Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should at least change `navbar-toggleable-md` to `navbar-expand-md` and `navbar-inverse` to `navbar-dark bg-dark`.

These classes were changed in the beta.